# Why does the event 'fadein' run twice in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is no problem when I press esc key or any other key to make the popup window disappear(**e.g.** `event.keycode == 37 or else`). However, I press the enter key and the popup window disappears, popup window pops up again. What is the problem?

```
    $(related-popup-open-button-id).on('click', fadeIn);

    functionfadeIn () {
        $(related-popup-id).fadeIn(1000);
    };

    $(related-popup-close-button-id).on('click', fadeOut);

    function fadeOut () {
        $(related-popup-id).fadeOut(1000);
    };

    $(document).on('keydown', push);

    function push(event) {
        if(event.keycode == 13) {
            $(related-popup-id).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    };
```

---

sorry, I add jsfiddle link below.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af75pm9o/)

Comment: `functionfadeIn` is a syntax error. `$(related-popup-open-button-id)` is a ReferenceError unless you have variables called `related`, `popup`, `open`, `button`, and `id`. Please post actual code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Can you put the html code too? it will be for users to understand and answer quickly.

Comment: @Paulpro sorry, could you check jsiffdle link? I have just added.

Comment: @RV sorry. I have just added.

Comment: Why remove the fiddle?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] in the question itself. Make it as easy as possible for us to help  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change focus when you open popup.

```
$('#popup-open-btn').on('click', fadeShow);

function fadeShow () {

    $('#popup').fadeIn(500);
    $("#popup-close-btn").focus();
};

$('#popup-close-btn').on('click', fadeClose);

function fadeClose () {
    $('#popup').fadeOut(500);
};

$(document).on('keydown', push);

function push(event) {
    if(event.which === 13) {
        $('#popup').fadeOut(500);
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b8yhtkxz/

Comment: This will get focus on your close button(of popup) instead of your open popup button.

Comment: becoz enter will trigger click event of whichever element is focused.